# How to get the list of classes derived from a given class, with enhanced RTTI?

Tags: delphi, rtti

I need to get a list of form types, but only for types derived from a given base form.

I use Delphi 2010 and enhanced RTTI to browse types

My current code is:

```
rc := TRTTIContext.Create;
rtyps := rc.GetTypes;
for rtyp in rtyps do
begin
  if not(rtyp.IsInstance) then Continue;

  // Now I need to check if rtyp.AsInstance.MetaclassType is derived from TMyBaseForm
end;
```

I dont want to instanciate an object and use the 'is' operator, as it would not execute in a timely manner.
As a current workaround, I test if a method, introduced in TMyBaseForm, was found in the RTTI context:

```
if (rtyp.GetMethod('MyMethod') = nil) then Continue;
```

but this is not a clean solution, as it can lead to issue if a method with the same name was introduced in another class branch.

So, my question:  **is there a regular way to detect if a class type is derived from another class type?**

Thanks,

Comment: I don't know how to implement it using RTTI, but there's the [ClassParent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.TObject.ClassParent) function. It returns the type of the immediate ancestor of a class. Or if you need to find out if a particular class type or object is an instance of a class or one of its descendants use [InheritsFrom](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.TObject.InheritsFrom) function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you call the `AsInstance`  returns a  [TRttiInstanceType](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/RTTI.TRttiInstanceType) , from there you must access the [`MetaclassType`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/RTTI.TRttiInstanceType.MetaclassType) property wich is a [TClass](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/System.TClass) reference to the reflected type, finally using the TClass you can call the [`InheritsFrom`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/System.TObject.InheritsFrom) function

```
for rtyp in rtyps do
if (rtyp.TypeKind=tkClass) and rtyp.IsInstance and rtyp.AsInstance.MetaclassType.InheritsFrom(TMyBaseForm) then
begin

  // do something
end;
```